# Regexp with differen t(unknown) string matching

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to grab ALL HREF links using the GoColly framework but
only allow urls of ANY domain to be Root URL's or SubDomains(NO
paths). I've commented out my REGEXP. The file extensions doesn't
matter. I just don't want anything after a "/". I've tried using the
variable "Domain" and concat to build a "varied" regexp. Not even sure
if that's a thing.

1. Twitter.Com - TRUE
2. hello.authac.com - TRUE
3. whole.facebook.com -TRUE
4. twiiter.com/dd -FALSE
5. hello.authac.com/sd.html FALSE
6. whole.facebook.com/sdsd/dsd/as.txt FALSE

   ```
   // Main
   package main
   import (
   "log"
   "fmt"
   "time"
   //"regexp"
   "net/http"
   "github.com/gocolly/colly"
   )

   var Target string
   var Domain string


   func main() {
   //r := regexp.MustCompile("(https:" + Domain + ".com)$")


   c := colly.NewCollector(
       //colly.URLFilters(r),

   )





   c.OnError(func(r *colly.Response, err error) {
       fmt.Println(r.Request.URL, "Is Not Reachable", r.StatusCode) 
   })



   // Find and visit all links
   c.OnHTML("a", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
       e.Request.Visit(e.Attr("href"))
   })


   c.OnRequest(func(r *colly.Request) {
       Domain := r.URL.String()
       Target := BannerGrab(Domain)
       fmt.Println(Target)
       fmt.Println("Dropping By.. ", r.URL)
       time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
   })

   c.Visit("https://www.twitter.com/")
   }

   //CheckDB if not listed else add
   //RiskDB
   //Email


   func BannerGrab(s string) string {

   client := &http.Client{}
   req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", s, nil)
       if err != nil {
       log.Fatalln(err)
   }
   req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Authac/0.1")
   resp, _ := client.Do(req)
   serverEntry := resp.Header.Get("Server")
   return serverEntry

   }
   ```

Comment: Hello, you just want true or false matches based on the presence or absence of a "/", or you want to match anything before the "/" anyway, to extract the root URL?

Comment: I want to match anything before the / to only allow domain grabbing of ROOT URL's. Your question is a little funky with how Go-Colly work but in a essence. Root URL's and subdomains should be the only thing that I get when println comes up.

Answer (score 0):

A possible regex is:

```
/ ^[^\/\\]+$ / gmi
```

Which does not match any time there is a "\" or "/" in the text.

Comment: golang regex's don't support flags like `gmi`, and don't require delimiters like `/`. Also this regex is just not going to work because `https://twitter.com` should be accepted as per OP's question

Comment: Agreed, but he specified "I just don't want anything after a "/"."

Answer (score 0):

The bellow regex can match URLs with only domain and subdomain with no path,

> r := regexp.MustCompile("(https|http)://(.*?)")

To add, **colly.URLFilters** will only crawl URL's matching the pattern. It will also not be creating URL's matching the pattern from the full URL and then do crawling.

Comment: The suggested example didn't work. Am I looking at colly.URLFilters and colly.Disallow backwards? It should only crawl root and subdomains with the above regex yet it stills traverse beyond that.